# Make Placeholder Dependence

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm using make to copy files to a `DEST` directory. I have the following rule

```
$(THUMBS): $(DEST)/% : %
    mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    cp $^ $@
```

The problem is that sometimes the source file may not exist. Rather than generating an error, I would rather copy a placeholder file instead.

I tried adding the placeholder as a dependence with the actual sources as intermediates. That kind of worked, but then if the placeholder is updated make overwrites all of the actual source files with it.

Is there an elegant way to accomplish this?

Comment: Are the files in `$(DEST)/%` being built by the makefile, or are they from some external process?

Comment: `DEST` has the same directory structure as the directory of the makefile. The source files are being built in the makefile's directory with an external process. That's why the rule just strips off the `DEST` part of the target.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the files in `$(DEST)` are being built externally (that is, not via a make recipe), then you can do this by embedding a little shell script in your recipe:

```
$(THUMBS):
    mkdir -p $(@D)
    for file in $(DEST_FILES); do\
        if [[ -f $file ]]; then\
            cp -f $file $@;\
        else\
            cp -f $(PLACEHOLDER_FILE) $@;\
        fi;\
    done
```

You aren't listing the files in `$(DEST)` as prerequisites, so make should never try to rebuild them.  You will need to set `PLACEHOLDER_FILE` to the name of the placeholder file that you wish to use for missing files, and set `DEST_FILES` to the list of files that you expect to see in `DEST`.  The downside is that without prerequisites, make won't know when it doesn't actually need to re-run this rule.  You will run it unconditionally every time.

Comment: I have accepted this answer since it works, but ultimately this felt like too much of a hack with make. I ended up totally redoing things in rake, which was way easier!

Comment: @Max: I agree, I'm not a big fan of this technique either.  Another option is to modify the external process that creates your `$(DEST)/*` files and have it create the placeholder files as needed.  Depending on exactly how that process is implemented, this approach might make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
$(DEST)/% : %
    mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    cp $^ $@

$(DEST)/% :
    mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    touch $@
```

Comment: I tried this and make complains about ignoring/overriding old commands.

Comment: @Max: which version of Make are you using? (`make -v`)